# How to deploy an UDP server @ Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am quite new at Docker and Cloud Run, so maybe I am missing something.

I've developed an UDP server and generate its docker container.

When I try it locally it works like charm.... but when I try to deploy it at Google Cloud Run It is not working. Aparently the healthcheck verifies the TCP port instead of the UDP.

Any ideas arround?

Cheers!

I've already try locally :

```
docker run -p 8080:4114/udp  gcr.io/myproject/udpserver
```

and I tried to deploy at Cloud Run with:

```
gcloud beta run deploy udpserver --image gcr.io/myproject/udpserver
```

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4114/udp
CMD python ./app.py
```

Answer (score 3):

That's right, it won't work with UDP.  The documentation for the [container contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract) (the rules you have to follow when building an image) say that you have to run an HTTP server on the port given in the PORT environment variable (8080).  HTTP is implied to run on TCP, not UDP.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply @Doug Stevenson .  I feel I little confuse because following this doc: 

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/RevisionSpec



At container port section, It seems that you can configure it as an UDP service, but I dont have a clue how to apply that config...

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if that API implies that UDP can be configured.  The documentation I linked is pretty explicit about requiring HTTP.

Comment: @Luis - Are you using Cloud Run or Cloud Run on GKE? The document that you are referencing is "Alpha" for Cloud Run on GKE. You will need to sign up to access Alpha features. I do not expect this feature for Cloud Run (non GKE).

Comment: Catch it! Thanks for your replies guys! Appreciate It !